# Application for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, screen-size

In my application i have used some custom buttons/icon,i have all images in the folder drawable-hdpi and this line  in the AndroidManifest.xml file
:

```
 <supports-screens  
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"  
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

My application is looking good in HTC desire(480x800) and HTC wildfire (320x400) without putting any image in `drawable-mdpi/ldpi` folder.

I want to know that, is it necessary to keep images in `drawable-mdpi/ldpi`
or 
it will also look good on different devices.

Comment: How would we know? It's rather dependent on your application...

Comment: @Kheldar : i knw it depends on my app but , after reading supporting multiple screen size i found most of the places to put images of different size in the {hdpi, mdpi, ldpi}folders my app is working good without putting any image in drawable-mdpi/ldpi ,so i was confused whether is it right or not..stack overflow has lots of experienced developer ..they could help me that's why i asked this ques..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For -optimal- results you should have the 3 versions of the images/icons {hdpi, mdpi, ldpi} but **it's not mandatory**.